# python script to fetch xml data in json using API

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to fetch data in `json` format but the dummy `api` which I am using has data in `xml` format, I am using below logic , Is there any other way I can try

```
import requests
import xmltodict
import json
 
url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml"
 
response = requests.get(url)
content=xmltodict.parse(response.text)
print(content)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need output in json format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json.loads()` with `json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(response.text))` as argument, i.e.:

```
import requests
import xmltodict
import json
 
url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml"
 
response = requests.get(url)
content = json.loads(json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(response.text)))
print(content)
```

---

Output:

```
{'CATALOG': {'PLANT': [{'COMMON': 'Bloodroot', 'BOTANICAL': 'Sanguinaria canadensis', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$2.44', 'AVAILABILITY': '031599'}, {'COMMON': 'Columbine', 'BOTANICAL': 'Aquilegia canadensis', 'ZONE': '3', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$9.37', 'AVAILABILITY': '030699'}, {'COMMON': 'Marsh Marigold', 'BOTANICAL': 'Caltha palustris', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Sunny', 'PRICE': '$6.81', 'AVAILABILITY': '051799'}, {'COMMON': 'Cowslip', 'BOTANICAL': 'Caltha palustris', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$9.90', 'AVAILABILITY': '030699'}, {'COMMON': "Dutchman's-Breeches", 'BOTANICAL': 'Dicentra cucullaria', 'ZONE': '3', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$6.44', 'AVAILABILITY': '012099'}, {'COMMON': 'Ginger, Wild', 'BOTANICAL': 'Asarum canadense', 'ZONE': '3', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$9.03', 'AVAILABILITY': '041899'}, {'COMMON': 'Hepatica', 'BOTANICAL': 'Hepatica americana', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$4.45', 'AVAILABILITY': '012699'}, {'COMMON': 'Liverleaf', 'BOTANICAL': 'Hepatica americana', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$3.99', 'AVAILABILITY': '010299'}, {'COMMON': 'Jack-In-The-Pulpit', 'BOTANICAL': 'Arisaema triphyllum', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$3.23', 'AVAILABILITY': '020199'}, {'COMMON': 'Mayapple', 'BOTANICAL': 'Podophyllum peltatum', 'ZONE': '3', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$2.98', 'AVAILABILITY': '060599'}, {'COMMON': 'Phlox, Woodland', 'BOTANICAL': 'Phlox divaricata', 'ZONE': '3', 'LIGHT': 'Sun or Shade', 'PRICE': '$2.80', 'AVAILABILITY': '012299'}, {'COMMON': 'Phlox, Blue', 'BOTANICAL': 'Phlox divaricata', 'ZONE': '3', 'LIGHT': 'Sun or Shade', 'PRICE': '$5.59', 'AVAILABILITY': '021699'}, {'COMMON': 'Spring-Beauty', 'BOTANICAL': 'Claytonia Virginica', 'ZONE': '7', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$6.59', 'AVAILABILITY': '020199'}, {'COMMON': 'Trillium', 'BOTANICAL': 'Trillium grandiflorum', 'ZONE': '5', 'LIGHT': 'Sun or Shade', 'PRICE': '$3.90', 'AVAILABILITY': '042999'}, {'COMMON': 'Wake Robin', 'BOTANICAL': 'Trillium grandiflorum', 'ZONE': '5', 'LIGHT': 'Sun or Shade', 'PRICE': '$3.20', 'AVAILABILITY': '022199'}, {'COMMON': 'Violet, Dog-Tooth', 'BOTANICAL': 'Erythronium americanum', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$9.04', 'AVAILABILITY': '020199'}, {'COMMON': 'Trout Lily', 'BOTANICAL': 'Erythronium americanum', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$6.94', 'AVAILABILITY': '032499'}, {'COMMON': "Adder's-Tongue", 'BOTANICAL': 'Erythronium americanum', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$9.58', 'AVAILABILITY': '041399'}, {'COMMON': 'Anemone', 'BOTANICAL': 'Anemone blanda', 'ZONE': '6', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$8.86', 'AVAILABILITY': '122698'}, {'COMMON': 'Grecian Windflower', 'BOTANICAL': 'Anemone blanda', 'ZONE': '6', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$9.16', 'AVAILABILITY': '071099'}, {'COMMON': 'Bee Balm', 'BOTANICAL': 'Monarda didyma', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$4.59', 'AVAILABILITY': '050399'}, {'COMMON': 'Bergamot', 'BOTANICAL': 'Monarda didyma', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$7.16', 'AVAILABILITY': '042799'}, {'COMMON': 'Black-Eyed Susan', 'BOTANICAL': 'Rudbeckia hirta', 'ZONE': 'Annual', 'LIGHT': 'Sunny', 'PRICE': '$9.80', 'AVAILABILITY': '061899'}, {'COMMON': 'Buttercup', 'BOTANICAL': 'Ranunculus', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$2.57', 'AVAILABILITY': '061099'}, {'COMMON': 'Crowfoot', 'BOTANICAL': 'Ranunculus', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$9.34', 'AVAILABILITY': '040399'}, {'COMMON': 'Butterfly Weed', 'BOTANICAL': 'Asclepias tuberosa', 'ZONE': 'Annual', 'LIGHT': 'Sunny', 'PRICE': '$2.78', 'AVAILABILITY': '063099'}, {'COMMON': 'Cinquefoil', 'BOTANICAL': 'Potentilla', 'ZONE': 'Annual', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$7.06', 'AVAILABILITY': '052599'}, {'COMMON': 'Primrose', 'BOTANICAL': 'Oenothera', 'ZONE': '3 - 5', 'LIGHT': 'Sunny', 'PRICE': '$6.56', 'AVAILABILITY': '013099'}, {'COMMON': 'Gentian', 'BOTANICAL': 'Gentiana', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Sun or Shade', 'PRICE': '$7.81', 'AVAILABILITY': '051899'}, {'COMMON': 'Blue Gentian', 'BOTANICAL': 'Gentiana', 'ZONE': '4', 'LIGHT': 'Sun or Shade', 'PRICE': '$8.56', 'AVAILABILITY': '050299'}, {'COMMON': "Jacob's Ladder", 'BOTANICAL': 'Polemonium caeruleum', 'ZONE': 'Annual', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$9.26', 'AVAILABILITY': '022199'}, {'COMMON': 'Greek Valerian', 'BOTANICAL': 'Polemonium caeruleum', 'ZONE': 'Annual', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$4.36', 'AVAILABILITY': '071499'}, {'COMMON': 'California Poppy', 'BOTANICAL': 'Eschscholzia californica', 'ZONE': 'Annual', 'LIGHT': 'Sun', 'PRICE': '$7.89', 'AVAILABILITY': '032799'}, {'COMMON': 'Shooting Star', 'BOTANICAL': 'Dodecatheon', 'ZONE': 'Annual', 'LIGHT': 'Mostly Shady', 'PRICE': '$8.60', 'AVAILABILITY': '051399'}, {'COMMON': 'Snakeroot', 'BOTANICAL': 'Cimicifuga', 'ZONE': 'Annual', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$5.63', 'AVAILABILITY': '071199'}, {'COMMON': 'Cardinal Flower', 'BOTANICAL': 'Lobelia cardinalis', 'ZONE': '2', 'LIGHT': 'Shade', 'PRICE': '$3.02', 'AVAILABILITY': '022299'}]}}
```